# Trouble converting NSString to a NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have looked at other examples and I am still not able to convert this string to a date. After i run this code I get the following output from the NSLogs:

Prediction Conversion: 2012-07-01 00:00:00 +0000

Timestamp Conversion: 2012-06-24 00:00:00 +0000

Prediction: 604800.000000

Which isn't the hard coded dates i used. Does anyone know why? Code is below:

```
NSString *timeStamp = @"20120620 19:23";//[[predictionData objectAtIndex:0 ] valueForKey:@"tmstmp"];
    NSString *predictionTime = @"20120620 19:30";// [[predictionData objectAtIndex:0 ] valueForKey:@"prdtm"];


    NSDateFormatter *ts = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [ts setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:dd"];
    NSDate *convertedTS = [ts dateFromString:timeStamp];

    NSDateFormatter *pt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [pt setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:dd"];
    NSDate *convertedPT = [pt dateFromString:predictionTime];

    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [convertedPT timeIntervalSinceDate:convertedTS];



    NSLog(@"Prediction Conversion: %@", [convertedPT description]);
    NSLog(@"Timestamp Conversion: %@", [convertedTS description]);

    NSLog(@"Prediction: %f", timeDifference);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using dd for your minutes instead of mm. This:

```
[ts setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:dd"];
```

Should be this:

```
[ts setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:mm"];
```

Comment: with that fixed the formatter is still getting the day and hour wrong from the string. I am not getting Prediction Conversion: 2012-06-21 00:30:00 +0000 Timestamp Conversion: 2012-06-21 00:23:00 +0000

Answer (score 1):

You formatter string is incorrect.

```
HH:dd
```

should be

```
HH:mm
```

In addition, you need to take the timezone into consideration. Without `+XXXX` specified, UTC is used by default. To set the timezone:

```
[ts setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone /*timezone*/]];
```

where `/*timezone*/` is specified by the [`NSTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. There are many different ways of using a timezone (and many different timezones), so choose the one that is best for you.

Comment: with that fixed i am still getting:

Comment: Prediction Conversion: 2012-06-21 00:30:00 +0000
Timestamp Conversion: 2012-06-21 00:23:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the locale, set it to `en_us_POSIX`.

```
ts.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_us_POSIX"];
```

also, it should be `HH:mm`, not `dd`

Comment: with that fixed the formatter is still getting the day and hour wrong from the string. I am not getting Prediction Conversion: 2012-06-21 00:30:00 +0000 Timestamp Conversion: 2012-06-21 00:23:00 +0000